# How to show points in highcharts when the zAxis value is 0?

Tags: highcharts

When creating a bubble chart in highcharts the zAxis determines how big the bubble will be but if the value is 0 then no bubble at all is shown, I'd like to show the bubble even when the value is 0 for the zAxis, the xAxis and yAxis still show valuable information.

I can of course set the value manually to one, but really I'm looking for a cleaner way of doing this, perhaps the api has something I'm not aware of.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @code4jhon, Bubbles with `0` z value are shown by default - according to the `minSize` property (default 8). Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eq946pr5/

Comment: I see it must be a matter of the version, we are on version 6, I increased by one the values for all the points then just corrected it in the tooltip to the right values, nice to see this is the default in version 8, thanks @ppotaczek

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. It works in the same way in version 6, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qmubf1gn/

Comment: hmmm ok then something else must be causing it to behave like this on my side, thanks @ppotaczek